# how to set value in orchard core text field in asp net core

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to write my own API to fill an orchard core content type which has several text field. for example the content type named "**test**" has two fields named first name and last name and are text fields.
I know by using contentItem.Content.test.firstName.Text.Value I can get the value. but as I use contentItem.Content.test.firstName="Mary" and then calling createAsync, just a new content Item is created which is empty.
would you please help me?
thanks

ps:test is the part name too

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more details of what is your problem?  What have you tried so far and what was the result?  What references have you reviewed?

Comment: I solved the problem.I shod create a dynamic Json variable and use that variable

Comment: here is part of my code: 
                string jsonLastName = $@"{{Text: '{LastName}'}}";
                string jsonAddress = $@"{{Text: '{Address}'}}";

                
                JObject rssLastName = JObject.Parse(jsonLastName);
                JObject rssAddress = JObject.Parse(jsonAddress);

 
                contentItem.Content.WebSiteAgentRegistration.LastName = rssLastName.First.Root;
                contentItem.Content.WebSiteAgentRegistration.Address = rssAddress.First.Root;

Comment: Soudabeh in the future please post your code inside of the question.  Please look here for best practices regarding questions on Stack Overflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using dynamic object variable